# Liquid: How can I get the variant Id of a product on Checkout.liquid?

Tags: javascript, liquid

I'm using `schema` to customize the way user can set things on Shopify.
So my code is like this:

```
{
    "type": "number",
    "id": "product_variant_id",
    "label": "Product ID"
}
```

If I run a console log on this i'm getting product handle:

```
product-handle-from-collection-x
```

It is possible to retrieve the first product variant ID of this product?

- I tried to use `{{ all_products["product-handle-from-collection-x"].variants.id }}`
- It works on Product Page. Not on Checkout

Comment: Try this code {{ all_products["product-handle-from-collection-x"].variants.first.variant.id }}

Comment: I tried that. I also tried to use `all_products['product-handle'].first_available_variant.id` and it look's like it only work on Product Page. Checkout liquid page i'm not sure why it doesn't. Thank you